# Negative matching between two data sets in R or unix

Tags: r

I'm still new in statistics and have problem with finding negative matching between two datasets that are containing 19000 and 18000 lines. I tried

```
diff -u file1 file2
```

in unix but `diff` is using some shortened syntax so the line count is not accurate. I also tried

```
grep -v file1 file2
```

but it is returning all the lines from file2. I'm using R and unix, so any help is good! 
Let's say my data looks like this:

```
File1   a b c d f g h i  
File2   a b c e f g j k
```

What I would like to get is a list that look like this:

```
d 
e
h
j
i
k
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
setdiff(c(File1, File2), intersect(File1,File2))
[1] "d" "h" "i" "e" "j" "k"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for unique lines

```
sort file1 file2 | uniq -u
```